# How to fill Gtk::TreeModelColumn with a large dataset without locking up the application

Tags: gtkmm, treemodel, large-data

I need to fill in a large (maybe not so much - several thousands of entries) dataset to a Gtk::TreeModelColumn. How do I do that without locking up the application. Is it safe to put the processing into separate thread? What parts of the application do I have to protect with a lock then? Is it only the Gtk::TreemodelColumn class, or Gtk::TreeView widget it is placed in, or maybe even surrounding frame or window?

Comment: Is the content generated dinamically during program execution? If not, you could have the `TreeModelColumn` object pre-calculated at the beginning.

Comment: no, the content is dynamically generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general approaches you could take. (Disclaimer: I've tried to provide example code, but I rarely use gtkmm - I'm much more familiar with GTK in C. The principles remain the same, however.)

One is to use an [idle function](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1SignalIdle.html) - that runs whenever nothing's happening in your GUI. For best results, do a small amount of calculation in the idle function, like adding one item to your treeview. If you return `true` from the idle function, then it is called again whenever there is more processing time available. If you return `false`, then it is not called again. The good part about idle functions is that you don't have to lock anything. So you can define your idle function like this:

```
bool fill_column(Gtk::TreeModelColumn* column)
{
    // add an item to column
    return !column_is_full();
}
```

Then start the process like this:

```
Glib::signal_idle().connect(sigc::bind(&fill_column, column));
```

The other approach is to use threads. In the C API, this would involve `gdk_threads_enter()` and friends, but I gather that the proper way to do that in gtkmm, is to use `Glib::Dispatcher`. I haven't used it before, but [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glibmm/unstable/thread_2dispatcher_8cc-example.html#_a3) is an example of it. However, you can also still use the C API with gtkmm, as pointed out [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/gtkmm-list@gnome.org/msg02166.html).